# Group by Clause on a query SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have managed to separate semi colon separated value to multiple rows in sql 2008 what i need now i to have Count(*) statement on it

```
ID Answers
1  Agent;Department Store
2  Distributor;Wholesaler
```

using

```
 SELECT ID,  
 Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS String  
 FROM  (SELECT ID,  
     CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(Question1, '; ', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
 FROM  Registrations) AS A CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```

I can get

```
ID  String
1   Agent
1   Department Store
2   Distributor
2   Wholesaler
```

i just need to get the count(*) of Agent,Department store ..

can i do something like

```
 Select Count(*),String from ( ..above query.. ) group by string ?!
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what you do... you do realise how much separated lists in SQL smells right? They should be in a separate table for exactly this reason

Comment: Yes, place your query in a subquery so you can use the alias in the group by.

Comment: I do not believe count(*) requires a group by, so just experiment a little.

Comment: I cant put group by in the query :(

Comment: @Liath yes it should be in a different table with a FK but saving like this was done by another guy now i have to deal with this and get the answer :(

Answer (score 1):

Your attempted `query` is correct it does work

Do this

```
 select count(*) as Count1,String from
    (
    SELECT ID,  
     Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS String  
     FROM  (SELECT ID,  
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(Answers, ';', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
     FROM  #t) AS A CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
     )x

     group by x.String
```

OR like this?

```
select count(*) as Count1 from
        (
        SELECT ID,  
         Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS String  
         FROM  (SELECT ID,  
             CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(Answers, ';', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
         FROM  #t) AS A CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
         )x
```

[SEE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/18515)

Comment: and can i add one more Replace if i want to replace any row containing "other : xxx" to "Other"